# How do I alter the wordpress admin login page logo href and title of the admin login page logo?

Tags: wordpress

I want to change the wordpress admin login page logo href and title of the admin login page logo how can i do this?

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution [Here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/138695/how-do-i-change-the-login-logo-url-and-hover-title) or by placing this code in you themes function.php file

```
/* ==  Change Logo URL ==============================*/

function my_url_login(){
    return bloginfo('url');
}
add_filter('login_headerurl', 'my_url_login');


/* ==  Change Logo URL Hover Text ==============================*/
function my_url_login_hover(){
     return bloginfo('name');
}
add_filter('login_headertitle', 'my_url_login_hover');
```

Comment: You may also like to use this plugin for purposes to brand WP, i have used it in the past with success https://wordpress.org/plugins/white-label-cms/